# How check generic type/subtype

Tags: kotlin

I need a function that receives a list of `<T>`, and a return list of `<T>`, but does some logic with a list of `<Number>`

```
fun <T> listOfNumbers(list:List<T>):List<T>{
    return if (list is List<Number>) {
        list.slice(0..list.lastIndex step 2)
    } else list
```

that does not work, because kotlin erase type.

I'm trying to reify, something like that

```
inline fun <reified T> listOfNumbers(list:List<T>):List<T> {
    return when (T::class) {
        Number::class -> list.slice(0..list.lastIndex step 2) as List<T>
        else -> list
    }
}
```

but the condition doesn't work

main:

```
fun main() {
    println(listOfNumbers(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
    println(listOfNumbers(listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
}
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

expecting:

```
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you passed a `List<Int>` to your function, not a `List<Number>`. When you don't specify the type of the list in `listOf()`, it implicitly uses the most specific type. This would have worked:

```
println(listOfNumbers(listOf<Number>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
```

You can revise your function as follows to allow this to work for any subtype of Number:

```
inline fun <reified T> listOfNumbers(list:List<T>):List<T> {
    return when {
        T::class.isSubclassOf(Number::class) -> list.slice(0..list.lastIndex step 2)
        else -> list
    }
}
```

The above requires the [Kotlin reflection library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#jvm-dependency) if you're on JVM. Alternatively, you could use Java reflection by replacing `T::class.isSubclassOf(Number::class)` with `Number::class.java.isAssignableFrom(T::class.java)`.